# Linking several multiple tabs from Google sheets to an excel workbook

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a google sheet which has many tabs. I specifically want to link some of them to an excel file on my PC. When I try publishing and linking via 'get data from other sources', it seems to only link one of the tabs (first tab alone) to my excel file. Is there anyway to link more than one?

Comment: You can link multiple sheets to one tab to google-sheet then link that sheet to excel.

Comment: I did think of that but was trying to rid making a temporary sheet. Thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Comment: Where is the googlesheet if the excel file is on your pc?

Comment: Google sheet is in Google drive